Pytorch error :Trying to backward through the graph a second time
I am a beginner in Pytorch and encountered the following error while attempting to replicate the Moco V1 model using Python. Using repain_graph=True should be meaningless. Both the encoder and momentum_encoder have been tested and there are no issues with them under direct training.
RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time (or directly access saved tensors after they have already been freed). Saved intermediate values of the graph are freed when you call .backward() or autograd.grad(). Specify retain_graph=True if you need to backward through the graph a second time or if you need to access saved tensors after calling backward.
Pseudocode of the original paper
enter image description here
def train(train_loader, encoder, momentum_encoder, device, epochs, m):
    torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True)
    encoder_optimizer = optim.Adam(encoder.parameters(), lr=0.001)
    encoder.apply(xavier_init_weights)
    encoder.to(device)
    momentum_encoder.apply(xavier_init_weights)
    momentum_encoder.to(device)

    queue = Memory_queue(4)
    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    for batch_idx, (datas, _) in enumerate(train_loader, 1):
        encoder.eval()
        momentum_encoder.eval()
        datas = datas.to(device)
        q = encoder(datas)
        queue.put(q)

    for epoch in range(epochs):
        encoder.train()
        for batch_idx, (datas, _) in enumerate(train_loader, 1):  # 调整起始值为1
            encoder_optimizer.zero_grad()
            encoder.zero_grad()

            datas = add_noise(datas).to(device)
            datas_key1 = add_noise(datas).to(device)

            q = encoder(datas)
            k = momentum_encoder(datas_key1)

            k = k.detach()
            N, C = q.shape

            l_pos = torch.squeeze(torch.bmm(q.view(N, 1, C), k.view(N, C, 1)).to(device), dim=2)

            temp_queue = torch.cat(queue.get_all(), dim=0)
            K, _ = temp_queue.shape

            l_neg = torch.mm(q.view(N, C), temp_queue.view(C, K)).to(device)

            logits = torch.cat([l_pos, l_neg], dim=1).to(device)
            labels = torch.zeros(N).long().to(device)
            loss = criterion(logits, labels)

            loss.backward()
            encoder_optimizer.step()

            update_model_ema(encoder, momentum_encoder, 0.5)
            queue.put(q)

after trying
loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
this error appeared
RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.cuda.FloatTensor [128, 32]], which is output 0 of AsStridedBackward0, is at version 3; expected version 2 instead. Hint: the backtrace further above shows the operation that failed to compute its gradient. The variable in question was changed in there or anywhere later. Good luck!

I solved this problem myself later by adding the following
queue.view(C, K).detach()

operation. One thing I think I learned is that you need to block all the "roads" in the loss feedback.

Are you 100% sure this is what you want though? You won't have any gradient going through C and K.

Hello,Thank you very much for the reminder. But I chose to reproduce the architecture of Moco v2 later. In v2, queues are no longer used to store negative samples. So I bypassed the problem.
